# How to fix the problem with auto-incrementing id column while populating the database?

Tags: java, mysql

I continue working on the [project](https://github.com/invzbl3/RestApiApplication). While populating with the script, the `id` column does not increment for some reason.

I have the following `Employee` entity:

```
@Data
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity(name = "employee_entity")
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @JsonProperty("phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private double salary;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
    private String password;
    private String username;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(() -> "USER");
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In `application.properties` I have `DDL` *Hibernate* configuration as:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I have two scripts as `data.sql`:

```
/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: Employees                                             */
/*==============================================================*/
insert into Employees (firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, email, salary, role, password, username)
values ('Christiano', 'Ronaldo', '+421905123456', 'test@gmail.com', 50000.00, 'TEAM_LEADER', 'testPassword', 'C7'),
       ('John', 'Smith', '+421905123480', 'test2@gmail.com', 40000.00, 'PM', 'testPassword2', 'Jo'),
       ('Michael', 'Jackson', '+421905123400', 'test3@gmail.com', 30000.00, 'DEVELOPER', 'testPassword3', 'Mike'),
       ('Leonardo', 'DiCaprio', '+421905123450', 'test4@gmail.com', 20000.00, 'SCIENTIST', 'testPassword4', 'Leo'),
       ('Brad', 'Pitt', '+421905123455', 'test5@gmail.com', 10000.00, 'ENGINEER', 'testPassword5', 'Brad');

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: Projects                                              */
/*==============================================================*/
insert into Projects (name, abbreviation, customer)
values ('Dokazovi', 'DKZ', 'SoftServe'),
       ('CarRentalSystem', 'CRS', 'DevPlus'),
       ('MarketPlace', 'MP', 'EPAM');
```

`schema.sql`:

```
drop table if exists employees;

drop table if exists projects;

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: projects                                              */
/*==============================================================*/
create table projects
(
    name          varchar(100) not null,
    abbreviation  varchar(100) not null,
    customer      varchar(100) not null
) CHARACTER SET utf8;

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: employees                                             */
/*==============================================================*/
create table employees
(
    firstName   varchar(100) not null,
    lastName    varchar(100) not null,
    phoneNumber varchar(100) not null,
    email       varchar(100) not null,
    salary      double       not null,
    role        varchar(100) not null,
    password    varchar(100) not null,
    username    varchar(100) not null
) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

I have the question based on it:

How can I fix *incrementing* of this `id` on the code level?

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the [Unmitigated advice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9513184/unmitigated), I've fixed it by changing the annotation instead of:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

to

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```